# XSLT transform failing when initial tag not present

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Input XML

```
<web-inf>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>S1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>XXXX</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>S2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>YYYY</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>S1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>S2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-inf>
```

I want to add following `<zoom><boom>WHAT</boom></zoom>` under `<web-inf>` even if tag `<zoom>` doesn't exist already. If `<zoom>` tag exists with `<boom>` tag as value WHAT then i don't want to do anything. I am using following transform but its not working when `<zoom>` tag is not present at all. Any suggestions?

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="web-inf[not (zoom/boom='WHAT')]/zoom[last()]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <zoom><boom>WHAT</boom></zoom>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the template as below

```
<xsl:template match="web-inf[not(zoom/boom='WHAT')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <zoom>
            <boom>WHAT</boom>
        </zoom>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This gets rid of the web-inf tag and adds the new tags at the end. Not exactly what i intended to do. I want to add the new tag just below the <web-inf> at the start

Comment: You need to retain the `identity template` and add this updated template for adding the required elements.

Comment: Its adding in the end. Cant it be added in the beginning just under `<web-inf>` tag?

Comment: Yes. I have modified the solution. The `<xsl:applytemplates>` has been moved after the `<zoom>` element. It should now add `<zoom>` just under `<web-inf>` element.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: If the answer has worked for you, could you please accept the answer. [How to accept the answer and it's benefits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)